# how to retrieve only part of the column

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

I have here an issue. on the first col here, RFDTA. this is a legacy col; it has the sales person name, but towards the end of the col it has a string of '000000'

I would like to retrieve say the first 18 positions, this should remove for me the 0000
or if there is a more elegant way to do this, please let me know. But if not, how would i select only the first 18 of RFDTA? this db is db2 using in Crystal reports. the actual len is 40.

```
SELECT                                                                         
  ALL       T02.RFDTA, T01.IDDOCD, T01.IDSLR#, T01.IDPRT#, T01.IDSHP#,   T01.IDORD#,      
            IDSHP#*(IDNTU$) AS "VALUE"                                         
  FROM      ASTDTA.OEINDLID T01 INNER JOIN                                       
            ASTDTA.REFERRF T02                                                 
  ON        T01.IDSLR# = T02.RFSLC                                             
  WHERE     IDPRT# IN ('CMENV', 'CRCMBOX', 'CMPOUCH2', 'RGCHAING', 'RGBOX',    
            'PINBOX', 'PINBOX4', 'CRGBCS1S', 'CRGBC1S', 'CRGBC1M', 'CRGBC1L')  

    AND     RFCAT = '0025'                                                     
    AND     RFDTA <> '000000'                                                  
  ORDER BY  T01.IDSLR# ASC
```

Comment: [SUBSTR](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.1.0/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0000854.htm) should get you there.

Comment: or you could just use a replace to replace 000000 with ''

Comment: When you say `towards the end of the col`, is it a fixed-length column and are the zeros always in the same positions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the `0`s from the end of the string, but you don't know how many, then `trim()` is helpful:

```
select trim(trailing '0' from T02.RFDTA)
```

Answer (score 1):

`SUBSTR(T02.RFDTA,1,18)` will give you the first 18 bytes.

[SUBSTR](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.1.0/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0000854.htm)